How to sort biblatex-apa by reverse chronological order by year, month, day?
Is there a way to use \declareSortingTemplate{apa} in the settings.sty or in the preamble to make it so that the bibliographies are in the style of APA but are listed in reverse chronological order? This is for a CV that I'm creating, using A Customised CurVe CV.
.tex File:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading={subbibliography}, title={Theses},type=masterthesis]
\printbibliography[heading={subbibliography}, title={Scholarly Paper Presentations (Refereed},keyword={scholarlypresentation}]


\end{document}

.bib file:
     @masterthesis{test1,
      author = {Doe, John},
      year = 2022,
      title = {Test title},
      type = {Master's thesis},
      institution = {Test Institution},
keywords={theses}
    }
    
    @presentation{test2,
      author = {Doe, John},
      year = 2023,
      month = mar,
      day = 5,
      title = {Sample title},
      titleaddon = {Paper presentation},
      eventtitle = {Test Event},
      venue = {Test Venue},
keywords={scholarlypresentation}
    }

@presentation{test2,
      author = {John Doe and Bob Barker},
      year = 2023,
      month = mar,
      day = 8,
      title = {Sample title},
      titleaddon = {Paper presentation},
      eventtitle = {Test Event},
      venue = {Test Venue},
keywords={scholarlypresentation}
    }


You could use sorting=ddnt to "Sort by full date (descending), name, title."
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=apa,sorting=ddnt]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
     @masterthesis{test1,
      author = {Doe, John},
      year = 2022,
      title = {Test title},
      type = {Master's thesis},
      institution = {Test Institution},
keywords={theses}
    }
    
    @presentation{test2,
      author = {Doe, John},
      year = 2023,
      month = mar,
      day = 5,
      title = {Sample title},
      titleaddon = {Paper presentation},
      eventtitle = {Test Event},
      venue = {Test Venue},
keywords={scholarlypresentation}
    }

@presentation{test3,
      author = {John Doe and Bob Barker},
      year = 2023,
      month = apr,
      day = 8,
      title = {Sample title},
      titleaddon = {Paper presentation},
      eventtitle = {Test Event},
      venue = {Test Venue},
keywords={scholarlypresentation}
    }

\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}



Hmm, when I did that, it doesn't display any of the bibliographies.

@DerronBorders It works for me. Note that the "full date sorting schemes" were only added to biblatex in the most recent version (v3.20 released 2024-03-22), see https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1292. If you're on an older version of biblatex you should get errors about this and this will not work. If you cannot update you can copy the definition from https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/3fb03272292e96003b415c0493d01c5f33db1033/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def#L1974-L2013

@DerronBorders Can you show your .log file so we can which version of biblatex you have?

I definitely have the most up-to-date version as I downloaded MacTex a couple of weeks ago.

Anyway, I got it to work another way, see my response below. Thanks for your help, it did point me in the right direction!

So just adding sorting=ddnt to the options for biblatex did not work, but I was able to figure it out by declaring my own sorting scheme:
\RequirePackage[style=apa, sorting=ymdnt, backend=biber]{biblatex}


    \DeclareSortingScheme{ymdnt}{
      \sort{
        \field{presort}
      }
      \sort[final]{
        \field{sortkey}
      }
      \sort[direction=descending]{
        \field[strside=left,strwidth=4]{sortyear}
        \field[strside=left,strwidth=4]{year}
        \literal{9999}
      }
      \sort[direction=descending]{
        \field{month}
        \literal{9999}
      }
      \sort{
        \field{sortname}
        \field{author}
        \field{editor}
        \field{translator}
        \field{sorttitle}
        \field{title}
      }
      \sort{
        \field{sorttitle}
        \field{title}
      }
    }

